# Intellisense error when passing vector by const reference (but project builds)

Tags: c++, reference, visual-studio-2017, constants, intellisense

While attempting to pass a vector by const reference I'm receiving the following intellisense error (project builds successfully):

```
no instance of constructor "ObjOne::ObjOne" matches the argument list
argument types are: (std::vector<int, std::allocator<int>>)
```

[image]

I have commented in the below minimal reproducible example where the error occurs. Is there a known way to resolve issues such as these within visual studio 2017?

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <optional>

class ObjOne
{
public:
    ObjOne(const std::vector<int>& p1) {}
};

class ObjTwo
{
private:
    std::vector<int> testVec = { 1,2,3,4,5 };
    std::optional<ObjOne> optObjOne;
public:
    ObjTwo() {}
    void makeObjOne() 
    {
        this->optObjOne = ObjOne(this->testVec); // Issue arises here
    }
};


int main()
{
    auto myObjTwo = ObjTwo();
    myObjTwo.makeObjOne();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please reduce your problem to a [repro]. I cannot test what you are showing right now myself because the code is incomplete and I don't see any obvious issue (or I am overlooking it), maybe because there is too much irrelevant code.

Comment: There could be problems with the `vertex.h` or `texture.h` headers, so those should be added to the question.  Also check and make sure you don't have multiple copies of those headers sitting around in different directories.

Comment: @walnut I have updated the question with a `minimal reproducible example` as requested. Apologies for not having done this from the start.

Comment: @whitwhoa I cannot reproduce the error with your code on either GCC, Clang or MSVC, see https://godbolt.org/z/P88oNz. What compiler and compiler options are you using?

Comment: @walnut I am using MSVC via visual studio 2017. The only options that are being used are `/permissive- /GS` which I believe was enabled by default and `/std:c++ latest`

Comment: I just did a build and the build succeeds, but visual studio still displays the error message. Could this just be an issue with intellisense in visual studio?

Comment: @whitwhoa Yes if that is just an Intellisense note and not an actual build error please make that clear in your question. I see nothing in the code that is wrong. You probably just have Intellisense set up wrong (e.g. for the wrong C++ version, which should be C++17 for `std::optional` support). I cannot really help you with that though.

Comment: @walnut Thank you for taking the time to go through this. I will update my question to clarify that the issue appears to be with VS intellisense and not the actual build.

Comment: I have tested your issue in my side and there is no such error as your description. So I wonder if there is something wrong with your configuration. Please try to close VS instance and delete the `.vs` hidden folder under the solution path.After that, reopen your project and test whether the issue exists.  Besides, you can try to create a new empty c++ project and then add this file to test whether this issue persists

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Intellisense error when passing vector by const reference (but project
>   builds)

I have tested your sample in my latest VS2017 and **Intellisense** works well as expected. So l wonder there are some problems with your VS environment and Intellisnese.

**My environment**-- OS: `win10 1903`  VS:`VS2017 Community 19.9.20`

You could try my suggestions to troubleshoot your issue:

**As a suggestion**, if your VS2017 is not the latest version, you could update it to the latest version which may have a newer fix.

**1)** close VS instance, delete the `.vs` hidden folder, `bin` folder and `obj` folder

**2)** clean the VS Component Cache under C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\15.0_xxxxx\ComponentModelCache

**3)** open your project in VS and right-click on your project-->`Properties`-->`C/C++`-->`Language`-->set `C++ Language Standard` to `ISO C++ 17 Standard(/std:c++17)`

**In addition**, if these does not work ,please try to [do a repair](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/install/repair-visual-studio?view=vs-2019) in VS Installer in case the Intellisense is broken.

Hope it could help you.